# Center lightning:fileCard with css

Tags: css, style

I am trying to center this component within a column with css.

[image]

this is my code

```
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-m-bottom_large">

        <lightning:fileCard aura:id="fileAvatar" fileId="" description="" hideDescription="{!v.disabled}" />
        <lightning:fileUpload name="fileUploader" multiple="false" accept="{!v.filetype}" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
  </div>
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `slds-align_absolute-center` to the col div. eg:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-align_absolute-center....
```

Or use some flex magic (the above layouts are flexed too):

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-m-bottom_large" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div >
    <lightning:fileCard aura:id="fileAvatar" fileId="" description="" hideDescription="{!v.disabled}" />
    <lightning:fileUpload name="fileUploader" multiple="false" accept="{!v.filetype}" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited - moved style to top level, so there is a single div wrapping the file components. It's working properly now.